# Circumambulations around the Temple altar

Tags: beis-hamikdash, sukkot, mizbeach-altar, haqafoth

The Mishnah records the following ritual having been performed in the Temple on Sukkoth (Sukkah 4:5):

> בכל יום מקיפין את המזבח פעם אחת ואומרין אנא ה' הושיעה נא אנא ה'
> הושיעה נא רבי יהודה אומר אני והוא הושיעה נא אני והוא הושיעה נא אותו
> היום מקיפין את המזבח שבע פעמים
>
> Each day they would circle the altar one time and say: “Lord, please
> save us. Lord, please grant us success” (Psalms 118:25). Rabbi Yehuda
> says that they would say: Ani we-Hu, please save us. And on that day,
> the seventh day of Sukkoth, they would circle the altar seven times.

What are some other occasions that haqafoth (circumambulations) around the mizbeah (altar) would have been performed?

Comment: Any reason to assume that other such occasions existed?

Comment: @JoelK I seem to recall that circling the mizbeah was an aspect of one of the 'avodahs but don't recall which (it is possible that my memory is mistaken)

Comment: At the inauguration?

Comment: @Chatzkel I don't recall that being part of hanukath ha-bayith... can you point towards a source?

Comment: not exactly the same thing, but see Zevachim 6:3ish

Comment: @Heshy thanks, I would upvote such an answer, whilst keeping the question open to additional answers. Appreciate the input.